# To know the method to solve the given linear ordinary differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am encountering problem in finding the solution of a linear ordinary differential equation given as y''=xy. Please help me to think about this kind of differential equations.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The solutions of this kind of ODE cannot be expressed with a finite number of elementary functions. They can be written on the form of infinite series. A closed form requires to know some special functions which have to be learned at higher level of mathematics. https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14623310/Safari-on-the-country-of-the-Special-Functions-Safari-au-pays-des-fonctions-speciales

Answer (score 1):

$y''=x y$ is a very difficult differential equation, the solution of which being
$$y=c_1 \,\text{Ai}(x)+c_2\, \text{Bi}(x)$$ where appear [Airy functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function).

Answer (score 1):

It is a special type of equation named Airy Equation
Getting a series solution is easy.
Assume $ y(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_k x^k $.
Then obtain a recurrence relation by plugging it into the original equation and thus obtain the coefficients.

It's closed form solutions are $ Ai(x) = \int_0^\infty cos (t^3+xt) dt $ Airy's function of the first kind.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function